# Debugging my matrix multiplication algorithm in MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, matrix-multiplication, distributed

### 1. Goal

I am implementing [matrix multiplication by Fox method](http://www.lac.inpe.br/%7Estephan/CAP-372/Fox_example.pdf) for square `mxn` matrices `AB = C` and `world_size = 4` processors disposed as a topological mesh/grid:

```
P0-P1
|  |  
P2-P3
```

where `-` represents `mesh_r` (mesh_rows) communicator and `|` represents `mesh_c` (mesh_columns) communicator, build through `build_mesh` procedure.

### 2. My code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int process_rank, world_size;
    int mesh_rows, mesh_columns;
    int mesh_dimension = 2;
    int *process_coordinates;
    MPI_Comm mesh, mesh_r, mesh_c;
    int process_rank_mesh;
    int *A, *A_loc;
    int *B, *B_loc;
    int *C, *C_loc;
    int m, n, mloc, nloc;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    if (process_rank == 0) {
        m = n = /*world_size * 1*/ 2; // multiple of world_size = 4
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    A = fill_matrix(A, m, n);
    B = fill_matrix(A, m, n);
    C = (int*) calloc(m * n, sizeof(int));

    if (process_rank == 0) 
        mesh_rows = 2;

    if (is_divisible(world_size, mesh_rows))
        mesh_columns = world_size / mesh_rows;
    else {
        mesh_rows = 1;
        mesh_columns = world_size / mesh_rows;
    }
   
    MPI_Bcast(&mesh_rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&mesh_columns, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    process_coordinates = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    build_mesh(&mesh, &mesh_r, &mesh_c, process_rank, world_size, mesh_rows, mesh_columns, process_coordinates);
    MPI_Comm_rank(mesh, &process_rank_mesh); 
 
    mloc = m / mesh_rows;
    nloc = m / mesh_columns;

    handle_errors(m, n, world_size, process_rank);

    A_loc = (int*) calloc(mloc * nloc, sizeof(int));
    distribute(A, A_loc, m, n, mloc, nloc, world_size, mesh_rows, mesh_columns);
    
    B_loc = (int*) calloc(mloc * nloc, sizeof(int));
    distribute(B, B_loc, m, n, mloc, nloc, world_size, mesh_rows, mesh_columns);

    C_loc = (int*) calloc(mloc * nloc, sizeof(int));
    distribute(C, C_loc, m, n, mloc, nloc, world_size, mesh_rows, mesh_columns);

    int *A_loc_add = (int*) calloc(mloc * nloc, sizeof(int)); // blocco di A addizionale inviato dai processori sulla diagonale a quelli su mesh_r

    // START BMR

    memcpy(A_loc_add, A_loc, sizeof(A_loc) * mloc); 
    MPI_Bcast(A_loc_add, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, f(process_rank), mesh_r);
    
    // Compute Cij = AB for each process
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (process_rank == 0 || process_rank == 3)
            C_loc[i] += A_loc[i] * B_loc[i];
        else
            C_loc[i] += A_loc_add[i] * B_loc[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        // Broadcast
        memcpy(A_loc_add, A_loc, sizeof(A_loc) * mloc);
        MPI_Bcast(A_loc_add, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, !f(process_rank), mesh_r);

        // Rolling
        int *t_loc = (int*) calloc(mloc * nloc, sizeof(int)); // variabile temporanea necessaria per lo scambio
        memcpy(t_loc, B_loc, sizeof(B_loc) * mloc);   
        MPI_Status status;
        int mate; // P0 <-> P2 e P1 <-> P3 - that is B_loc swap in mesh_c communicator
        if (process_rank == 0) {
            mate = 2;
            MPI_Send(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        } else if (process_rank == 1) {
            mate = 3;
            MPI_Send(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        } else if (process_rank == 2) {
            mate = 0;
            MPI_Send(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        } else if (process_rank == 3) {
            mate = 1;
            MPI_Send(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, mate, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
        memcpy(B_loc, t_loc, sizeof(t_loc) * mloc);
        free(t_loc);

        // multiply
        dot_product(A_loc_add, C_loc, B_loc, m);
    }
    
    // END BMR
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void dot_product(int *A_loc_add, int *C_loc, int *B_loc, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        C_loc[i] += A_loc_add[i] * B_loc[i];
}

int f(int process_rank)
{
    if (process_rank == 0 || process_rank == 1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

void distribute(int *Mat, int *Mat_loc, int m, int n, int mloc, int nloc, int world_size, int mesh_rows, int mesh_columns)
{
    MPI_Datatype square_block;
    int stride = n;
    int count = mloc;
    int block_length = nloc;
    MPI_Type_vector(count, block_length, stride, MPI_INT, &square_block);
    MPI_Datatype square_block_resized;
    MPI_Type_create_resized(square_block, 0, sizeof(int), &square_block_resized);
    MPI_Type_commit(&square_block_resized);
    int *send_counts = (int*) calloc(world_size, sizeof(int));
    int *displs = (int*) calloc(world_size, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh_rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mesh_columns; j++) {
            send_counts[i * mesh_columns + j] = 1;
            displs[i * mesh_columns + j] = i * n * block_length + j * block_length;
        }
    }
    
    MPI_Scatterv(Mat, send_counts, displs, square_block_resized, Mat_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void handle_errors(int m, int n, int world_size, int process_rank)
{
    if (process_rank == 0) {
        if (m != n) {
            perror("Not square matrices\n");
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (world_size != 4) {
            perror("World size must be 4\n");
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

bool is_divisible(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    return dividend % divisor == 0;
}

void build_mesh(MPI_Comm *mesh, MPI_Comm *mesh_r, MPI_Comm *mesh_c, int process_rank, int world_size,
    int mesh_rows, int mesh_columns, int *process_coordinates) 
{
    int mesh_dimension = 2;
    int *mesh_n_dimension;
    int mesh_reorder = 0;
    int *mesh_period;
    int *remain_dims = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    mesh_n_dimension = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    mesh_n_dimension[0] = mesh_rows;
    mesh_n_dimension[1] = mesh_columns;
    mesh_period = (int*) calloc(mesh_dimension, sizeof(int));
    mesh_period[0] = mesh_period[1] = 0;
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mesh_dimension, mesh_n_dimension, mesh_period, mesh_reorder, mesh);
    MPI_Cart_coords(*mesh, process_rank, mesh_dimension, process_coordinates);
    remain_dims[0] = 0;  
    remain_dims[1] = 1;
    MPI_Cart_sub(*mesh, remain_dims, mesh_r);
    remain_dims[0] = 1;
    remain_dims[1] = 0;
    MPI_Cart_sub(*mesh, remain_dims, mesh_c);
}

int *fill_matrix(int *Mat, int m, int n)
{
    int k = 0;
    Mat = (int*) calloc(m * n, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            Mat[i * n + j] = ++k;
    return Mat;
}
```

### 3. Result

My algorithm is working fine if `m = 2`:

```
C00:
7

C01:
10

C10:
15

C11:
22
```

as you can see here

[image: correct]

but makes mistakes when calculating `C` for other values of `m` (e.g. `world_size * 1`):

```
C00:
58      92
242     308

C01:
78      120
294     368

C10:
198     260
494     588

C11:
274     344
602     704
```

whose expected result `C` is:

[image: expected result]

- Can you help me? You can use this [online matrices multiplication tool](https://matrix.reshish.com/multiplication.php) for debugging and calculate expected result. I am 100% sure that `build_mesh` and `distribute` procedures are correct: the bug must be in BMR section

Comment: You have sends and receives with hard-coded ranks. You should really 1. not use comm world but use your row/column communicators, and 2. write your send/recvs in terms of relative neighbors. 3. The Fox algorithm rotates data through rows/columns so your use of `MPI_Send/Recv` will deadlock. Use `MPI_Sendrecv`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thanks. Did you mean something like `int peer = (process_rank == 0) ? 2 : 1;  int tag_recv = tag_send = 0; MPI_Sendrecv(t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, peer, tag_send, t_loc, mloc * nloc, MPI_INT, peer, tag_recv, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE)`?

Comment: The Fox algorithm circulates, right? So you need `after = (rank+1)%comm_size` and similar before, and then `MPI_Sendrecv( tgt=after, src=before )`. So to speak. And that in both the row and column communicator. And stop doing everything 2x2. Write it completely general.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I can suppose there are only 4 processors, so it's okay for me to consider 2x2 mesh. There is no need to generalize. I need to generalize the matrix dimension

Comment: @VictorEijkhout How can I swap `t_loc` elements in `mesh_c` communicator (that is P0<->P2 and P1<->P3) avoiding hard-coded send and receive in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`?